# Lendo o json corretamente para gerar os dados para o gráfico (Ajax e Morris)

Tags: ajax, morris

https://github.com/rg3915/morris/blob/master/myproject/core/templates/core/persons_by_uf.html#L231-L263

Não estou conseguindo retornar o json via ajax, tentei com console.log mas está retornando a própria função que eu montei

```
function (){
            var json = null;
            $.ajax({
                async: false,
                global: false,
                url: "http://localhost:8000/uf/",
                type: 'GET',
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (data) {
                    json = data;
                    console.log(json);
                }
            });
            return json;
        }here
```

Como eu faço para retornar o json que eu já havia montado antes?

Tudo isso é pra gerar o gráfico, mas ele não está lendo o json corretamente.

Estou seguindo o tutorial deste site

https://www.daniweb.com/programming/web-development/threads/477322/morris-chart-with-dynamic-data

Comment: Essa url que você está apontando tem os dados que você precisa no formato JSON? Tenta pegar o resultado dessa url e testar em algum validador para ver se realmente está no formato JSON correto. (validador: http://jsonlint.com/). Uma forma de pegar o resultado da url é: Se você usa Google Chrome, aperta F12 e na aba "Network" você consegue ver os retornos dos Ajax, olha a imagem: http://prntscr.com/94dr9o

Answer (score -1):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    // Lê os dados, que já estão em json
    var json = function(callback){
        var json = null;
        $.ajax({
            url: "http://localhost:8000/uf/",
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
                json = data;
                callback(data);
            }
        });
        return json;
    };

    // Gera o gráfico de barras
    var grafico = function(dados) {
        Morris.Bar({
            element: 'barchart',
            data: dados,
            xkey: 'uf',
            ykeys: ['quant'],
            labels: ['quant'],
            hideHover: 'auto',
            resize: true,
        });
    };

    // Chamando a função para gerar o gráfico
    json(grafico);

    // Caso queira imprimir os dados no console
    /* json(function(json){
        console.log(json)
    }); */

</script>
```